# Как добавить плавности анимации к выпадающему меню на bootstrap?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap, меню

Подскажите плиз как добавить плавности анимации к выпадающему меню на bootstrap?
(вопрос помеченный как дубликат - удален)

```css
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ase;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="/">Бла</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="/">Бла</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- end dropdown-menu -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Задача решена самостоятельно

Answer (score 2):

Перевод логики с "`display:none;`" на "`opacity:0;`", как один из вариантов.

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876195/bootstrap-3-dropdown-transition) с примерами.

Comment: спасибо, но при opacity список появляется по всей области отображения, даже когда не наводишь по меню - мне же нужно, чтобы он появлялся при подведении к пункту менюшки

Comment: В тех же примерах автор использует .hover().

Comment: Вот оно решение - обнаружил на просторах сети - пользуйтесь на здоровье :)
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition:         all 0.2s  ase;
  -moz-transition:    all 0.2s  ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s  ease;
  -o-transition:      all 0.2s  ease;
  -ms-transition:     all 0.2s  ease;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

Comment: И там же советуют visible. Подходит и height: 0//auto. Невнимательность?

Comment: экспериментировал - в моем случае height: 0//auto не подходит точно.
белая подложка сворачивается наверх - остается только узкая полоска, а сам список оказывается голым - как бы подвешенный с абсолютной прозрачностью - как-то так..